# Flex-box discrepancy between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I have a table with two columns. I am using flex columns in order to have the second column center on each of the first columns items.

The problem is FireFox and Chrome do not display the same. I have to set a height to 1px in Chrome in order to stretch one div to 100% height. This makes the table in FireFox smashed.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJBWMK

SCSS

```
   @import "bourbon";

   table, td {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
   .container {
   height: 1px;
   }
   .flex-wrap {
   @include display(flex);
   @include flex-direction(column);
   @include justify-content(space-around);
   height:100%;
   }
```

HTML

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Col 1</th>
         <th>Col 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="container">
            <div class="flex-wrap">
               <div>
                  First Div <br/>
                  First Div <br/>
                  First Div <br/>
               </div>
               <div>
                  Second Div <br/>
                  Second Div <br/>
                  Second Div <br/>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="container">
            <div class="flex-wrap">
               <div>Center First Div</div>
               <div>Center Second Div</div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be a better idea to split the content (First div / Second div) into two rows. With your current structure, even with 1px hack, if you change from 3 line content to 2 line content in any one, then also, alignment in the second column will be disturbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why this code would work. Your `height: 1px` trick is a hack. It's non-standardized code. So browser behavior can vary.

If you must keep this code structure, consider switching from `height: 1px` to `min-height: 1px`.

Comment: Min-height breaks Chrome and Firefox. I've tried it.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is making the div parents flex containers, so they can stretch the divs full height. But even if that works, I wouldn't consider it stable across browsers.